Join/relate with one to many relation
Took GIS in undergrad 10 years ago and now trying to relearn some skills for my job in urban planning. Working in ArcGIS Pro, I've got a standalone table of historic permit data that I'd like to join to a map layer of our city's zones, with the ultimate goal of visualizing how many permits have been processed in each zone. Common attribute field is the parcel #. Problem I'm running into is that there are parcels where more than one permit has been processed. Is it possible to join/relate this table to this map layer so that parcels with multiple permit records display all permit records, rather than just displaying the first record with the corresponding parcel #.

Can you share what tool did you try and what was the results

The add join tools should do this. However, you need to have both the layer and the table in one geodatabase. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/add-join.htm

It is not join. Learn how to add attachments
